# Replacing an attribute's value in an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to replace an attribute's value in a certain `<div>`. I want it changed to a value that is provided by a CMS. There are multiple `<div>`'s with that variable.

Example:

```
    <div id="1395308878">
    <div class="slides_container">
    <div><a rel="fancy" href="01.jpg"><img border="0" src="01a.jpg"></a><div>
    <div><a rel="fancy" href="02.jpg"><img border="0" src="02a.jpg"></a><div>
    <div><a rel="fancy" href="03.jpg"><img border="0" src="03a.jpg"></a><div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="9995308878">
    <div class="slides_container">
    <div><a rel="fancy" href="04.jpg"><img border="0" src="04a.jpg"></a><div>
    <div><a rel="fancy" href="05.jpg"><img border="0" src="05a.jpg"></a><div>
    <div><a rel="fancy" href="06.jpg"><img border="0" src="06a.jpg"></a><div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I want the code rel="fancy" to be replaced by rel=the id-number (that is provided by the CMS). So the code has to be something like this:

```
    in the DIV with id="a number" <-- generated by CMS
    find the VAR fancy and replace it with the same number <-- that is generated by a CMS.
```

This has to be the result:

```
    <div id="1395308878">
    <div class="slides_container">
    <div><a rel="1395308878" href="01.jpg"><img border="0" src="01a.jpg"></a><div>
    <div><a rel="1395308878" href="02.jpg"><img border="0" src="02a.jpg"></a><div>
    <div><a rel="1395308878" href="03.jpg"><img border="0" src="03a.jpg"></a><div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="9995308878">
    <div class="slides_container">
    <div><a rel="9995308878" href="04.jpg"><img border="0" src="04a.jpg"></a><div>
    <div><a rel="9995308878" href="05.jpg"><img border="0" src="05a.jpg"></a><div>
    <div><a rel="9995308878" href="06.jpg"><img border="0" src="06a.jpg"></a><div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The number is every time unique to make sure that images stay in their own fancybox and is provided by the CMS. I can manipulate a template to make sure that number is inserted, but not in the place where "fancy" is positioned...

Comment: Just a terminology thing; what you're referring to (thing="stuff" inside an HTML element) is usually referred to as an Attribute, or HTML Attribute to be specific. When you mentioned "var" in reference to JavaScript, I tended to think of the JS-based way of declaring variables.

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you, explain how to write the code, or provide examples or references are off-topic. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and the full text of any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR)].

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)'s call back to get your job done,

```
$('.slides_container [rel]').attr('rel', function(){
  return $(this).closest('div[id]').attr('id');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u6J6d/1/)

Comment: I tried the first code and that seems to work. I'm going to test it now on multiple pages!

Comment: Tested every page and it works flawless. Thanks Rajaprabhu!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have stored the CMS id in a variable `cms_id`;

You can do the following in jquery

```
$("#"+cms_id +" a[rel = 'fancy']").attr("rel",cms_id)
```

Working Code [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/hNSP8/)

Comment: Could you please explain me the reason for down vote